# The Val() function doesn't recognize system-wide decimal point

Tags: ms-access, vba, number-formatting, decimal-point

The `val()` function seems to understand `.` as a decimal point, even on systems with `,` as a decimal point. For example, the following call

```
val("7,3") + 1,4
```

returns the real number `8,4` (`8.4` in English notation). `val("7.3") + 1,4` returns the expected value `8,7`.

Is this a feature or a bug? How can I specify which decimal point will be used in function `val()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/val-function-HA001228931.aspx):

> **Note** The `Val` function recognizes only the period (`.`) as a valid
>   decimal separator. When different decimal separators are used, as in
>   international applications, use `CDbl` instead to convert a string to a
>   number.

Note: `Val(7,3)+1,4` also returns `8,4`, so be careful if your input already is in the number format!

Comment: Very usefull, but note that `Cdbl("")` generates a `Type Mismatch` error.